# Does Blazor Server 7 need to call MapRazorPages()?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

When Visual Studio creates a Blazor server app, there's no call to app.MapRazorPages() in Program.cs

But I do see that call in a lot of examples. Is that something that used to be needed? Or should it be added back in?

I am using Asp.Net Core 7.

Comment: does this answer your question ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59806119/how-are-blazor-apps-able-to-expose-razor-pages-endpoints-without-a-call-to-mapra

Comment: @jeb Yes & no. The crux of the answer seems to be that MapRazorPages() is called by something else. On the flip side, I have no idea when/how PageActionEndpointConventionBuilder () is called nor that the call to EnsureRazorPagesServices () is equivalent (although by it's name, it likely does so). thanks for the link as it makes me a bit more confident that it's not necessary to call MapRazorPages().